# how to pad python figure text decimal with invisible zero

Tags: python, matplotlib

The padding of space to the print screen works well

```
a1 =    12
a2 = 00012
```

however space on the figure contracts, the decimals are misaligned!

```
a1 =   12
a2 = 00012
```

Example code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("a1 = {:5d}".format(12))
print("a2 = {:05d}".format(12))

plt.text(0.3,0.4,"a2 = {:05d}".format(12))
plt.text(0.3,0.5,"a1 = {:5d}".format(12))

plt.show()
```

[example figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iohea.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the font that is used. You need a mono-spaced font, so that all characters have the same width.

Try this instead:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("a1 = {:5d}".format(12))
print("a2 = {:05d}".format(12))
font = {"fontname": "Consolas"}

plt.text(0.3, 0.4, "a2 = {:05d}".format(12), **font)
plt.text(0.3, 0.5, "a1 = {:5d}".format(12), **font)

plt.show()
```

**Result:**
[image]

---

Or, if you want to set all of the text in the plot to monospace, you can just set the default value to monospace like this:

```
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'monospace'
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is for Windows.

For Linux can use

```
font = {"fontname": "DejaVu Sans Mono"}
```

Comment: Yes, my solution was specifically for Windows. The more stable and cross-platform answer is to set the `font.family` parameter like this: `plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'monospace'`